# Is it possible to use Google Adwords Api without RefreshToken?

Tags: api, google-api, google-ads-api

I requested RefreshToken from my customer to develop a web page for them by using google adwords Api. They responded my request like that ->
There is no need for Refresh Token to use Google Adwords Api.

Could you please answer me if it is possible or not? If it is possible how we can use Google Adwords Api without RefreshToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need an access token to access the adwords api that will expire after an hour.   You could probably use a service account authentication.  If they do give you a refreshToken remember you will also need the client id and secret used to create it in order to get the access token.

It is a also against Google terms of use to share the client credentials.  You will need to create your own project and have them authenticate it when they need to access their data. You will then have a refreshToken.